# Target param on Tabulator

Tags: tabulator

the "target:_blank" param on "formatter:link" don't work. 
I have this code

```
{width:40, align:"center", field:"pdf", formatter:"link", headerSort:false, formatterParams:{target:"_blank", label:pdfIcon, urlPrefix:"...myURL..."}}
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Which version of Tabulator are you using?

Comment: you also seem to be prefxing the url win an invalid prefix